# The Fountain: are those other spaceships?

Tags: the-fountain

I'm just wondering if my eyes were going or something:

Just before the end of the "future" timeline, Tommy is approaching the supernova in his bubble. For a brief moment he appears to pass by a group of similar bubbles.

I *did* see that right? Was there any indication in the film what they were doing there? They appeared to be close, but not *that* close, to the supernova. He spends some time continuing on after passing them by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going from memory but they were there and it wasn't stated why they were there but my guesses are:

**In story:** they were there to watch the fireworks of the death of their birth Sun.

**Out of Story:**  to show that humanity survives and reaches that point.

Comment: I like both of those answers!